# Function Object Literal Converted in ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to convert a function that has an object literal inside of it to a class and I am not sure how I would handle the object literal when converting to a class. Example:

```
function Commercial(channel, name) {
    this.recording = {
        isChannelLive: true,
        isNameRated: false,
        timeSlots: function() {
            this.active = false;
            this.recording = false;
        }
    };
}
```

So I am hoping to figure out how to do something like this:

```
class Commercial {
    constructor(channel, name) {
      this.channel = channel;
      this.name = name;
    }
    this.recording = {
        isChannelLive: true,
        isNameRated: false,
        timeSlots: function() {
            this.active = false;
            this.recording = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Don't know how to handle the object literal?

I am wanting to change the function to a class that will have a constructor for the channel and name, but not sure how to handle the object literal.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Just do it the same way in the constructor.

Comment: That `timeSlots` method is weird. Who would call it, on which object?

Comment: What is `this.recording` supposed to refer to in the `timeSlots` method?

Comment: This is a contrived example. If this question has gone off track, I can close and open a new one from comment below about the question being different than what was originally asked. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would put exactly the same code that is currently in the ES5 constructor into the ES6 classes constructor:

```
class Commercial {
    constructor(channel, name) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.name = name;
        this.recording = {
            isChannelLive: true,
            isNameRated: false,
            timeSlots: function() {
                this.active = false;
                this.recording = false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Now what if it is outside of the constructor? So I create my constructor and then have this.recording that is not in the constructor. Do I have to wrap the literal inside of a method?

Comment: @pertrai1 [This proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-public-fields) might interest you.

Comment: @pertrai1: What do you mean by "outside of the constructor"? If you have an instance, you just access its `.recording` property. Everything works quite like in ES5.

Comment: Hey, take a look at my edit and see if that makes sense

Comment: @pertrai1: What the code does makes more sense now, but the meaning of your question has definitely changed.

Comment: @gcampbell: I don't think the OP is looking for experimental syntactical sugar

Comment: @Bergi I know, it's a way of saying that JavaScript can't do this now but might be able to in the future.